# Magento add grid form to cms page

Tags: magento, grid, repeater

I want to create a module for add a dynamic grid on cms page like this:

[image]

I'm able to create custom field like text or file but I don't know how can I add (remove) multiple elements, I don't find any example/tutorial, can you give me some tips or some link?

edit:
studying magento code into Varien/data/form/gallery I find a way, I use gallery.php element as starting point and then I create my element, the problem is how to save the data, for now I save the data into a column as an array or json

```
    $aa = "[";        
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
    {
        $aa = $aa . $file["name"]["-1"] . ",";
    }
    $aa = $aa . "]";
    $aa = str_replace(",]","]",$aa);
    $model->setBackground($aa);
```

I,m able to get this value but I don't think is the best way, is better create a custom magento model?

Comment: Asking for examples, tutorials, tips, or external links are all off-topic on Stack Overflow. You need to write some code and come here with the specific problems you're facing with your code.

Comment: it's right, sorry! I edit my question!